# Does anyone know this Xcode Theme?

Tags: xcode, themes, xcode6

I've been looking for this theme everywhere, and I was wondering if anyone here knew it?

http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/07/20/swift-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's **Solarized Dark**, although it might be slightly modified.

You can reference it on https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Solarized-Dark-for-Xcode